# Git log tabular formatting

Tags: git, bash, scripting

I have a simple alias to display few last commits:

```
log --pretty=format:'%h %an %s' -10
```

How can I make the results to be displayed in columns, like this:

```
898e8789 Author1             Commit message here
803e8759 Other Author name   Commit message here
```

Comment: If there's a canned Unix utility to do this I'd love to know about it!  The best thing I can think of is Perl formatted output, which is a pain.

Comment: @Zack: man column is your friend.

Comment: That appears to be a BSDism, unfortunately.

Comment: it's in the util-linux package.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In Git 1.8.3 and later, there is native support for this in the [pretty format](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats), using the `%<(N)` syntax to format the next placeholder as *N* columns wide:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %<(20)%an %s' -10
```

For versions before 1.8.3, the previous version of this answer, retained below, should work.

Here's a solution in Bash using `read` to parse the log lines back apart, and `printf` to print them out, with a fixed width field for the authors name so the columns will stay lined up. It assumes that `|` will never appear in the author's name; you can choose another delimiter if you think that might be a problem.

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h|%an|%s' -10 | 
  while IFS='|' read hash author message
  do 
    printf '%s %-20s %s\n' "$hash" "$author" "$message"
  done
```

You can create this as an alias using:

```
[alias]
    mylog = "!git log --pretty=format:'%h|%an|%s' -10 | while IFS='|' read hash author message; do printf '%s %-20s %s\n' \"$hash\" \"$author\" \"$message\"; done"
```

I'm sure you could do this in fewer characters using `awk` but as [the saying](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247) goes,

> Whenever faced with a problem, some people say “Lets use AWK.” Now, they have two problems.

Of course, having said that, I had to figure out how to do it in `awk` which is a bit shorter:

```
git ... | awk -F '|' '{ printf "%s %-20s %s\n", $1, $2, $3 }'
```

Comment: While this works - using the native git-log method as Suggested by @Jesse is much neater

Comment: @SeanBurlington When I wrote this answer in 2010, that did not exist; support for the spacing placeholders was added [in 1.8.3, in 2013](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a57523428b4c08795e793356e12afc3de812f84a) (though for some reason, it seems to be [missing from the release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.3.txt)). Now that you have pointed out that there is a better solution available, I've incorporated that into my answer.

Comment: I hoped that the `%<(N)` syntax would work in other areas of Git where `--format` is used, but it seems to be limited to `--pretty` for now. In 2013 there was [some discussion](http://lists-archives.com/git/797299-for-each-ref-support-aligned-for-left-alignment.html) about using that syntax with `for-each-ref --format` and some experimentation with `%(...:aligned)` but that discussion seems to have died.

Comment: Is there any way to apply the fixed size to the graph as well? And to also truncate fields longer than the specified size? I'm trying to make a log with fixed positions for everything, as that's easier on the eyes.

Comment: note that for `for-each-ref` you can use `%(align:width=20,position=left)` in the formatting, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref

Answer (score 41):

You can also do:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %<(20)%an %s' -10
```

No need for shell magic or post processing with `awk`, `column` etc.

Comment: This seems like the best solution by far to me. Where did you find docs on the %<(20) syntax?

Comment: It's referenced in the `git help log` docs, under the PRETTY FORMATS section (I'm using git version 1.8.3.4).

Comment: This is the shortest yet most accurate answer. Don't need anything else, just built-in git log.

Comment: This is a new option in 1.8.3, so if you're using 1.8.3 or later, this is definitely a better solution. I've incorporated this suggestion into my answer, as it is on top due to being accepted and thus more likely to be the first thing people see when coming here.

Answer (score 20):

The following command will print the log in a tabular form

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h|%an|%s' -10 | column -t -s '|'
```

the [column](http://linux.die.net/man/1/column) command "columnates" the output, using the "|" as field separator, it will find out the optimal column width given the input, so it would work well even if you have more fields.

On Linux it will work ok as long as you don't use colors, the Linux implementation doesn't handle well the [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

But in Mac OS X, it will handle colors and you can use any unicode character as field delimiter. I use ∑ since I'm pretty sure it won't occur by chance on the commit text. `|` is a bad choice because it could appear in the commit description and also if you use `--graph --decorate --all` it will appear as part of the symbols used to draw the graph

Comment: First answer I saw that worked with this: `git log --pretty=format:'%cr|%s' -10 | column -t -s '|'`

Answer (score 16):

In order to get truly tabular format you need to also truncate usernames that are longer than e.g. 20 characters:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %<(20,trunc)%an %s' -10
```

Additionally, if you're outputting to the terminal, you may want to prevent line overflows by either truncating the commit message field:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %<(20,trunc)%an %<(39,trunc)%s' -10
```

or wrapping the lines and indenting any overflowing lines to align:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%w(79, 0, 29)%h %<(20,trunc)%an %s' -10
```

EDIT: The above example hard-codes the terminal width to be 79 characters. On POSIX systems you can use `tput cols` to return the width:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%w(`tput cols`, 0, 29)%h %<(20,trunc)%an %s' -10
```

or

```
git log --pretty=format:'%w($((`tput cols`-1)), 0, 29)%h %<(20,trunc)%an %s' -10
```

Unfortunately these last two break `git alias` so it will require a terminal alias (unless you really love typing).

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Hopefully this should help

Comment: thx for this `tput cols` part, thats very useful to make formats what are matching variable termin size :D

Answer (score 10):

## How to add a tab?

What you are looking for is:

## `%x09`

#### Here is an example

```sh
git log --pretty=format:"%C(magenta)%h %C(cyan)%C(bold)%ad%Creset %C(cyan)%cr%Creset%x09 | %s %C(green)%Creset" --date=short
```

I wanted the relative date to be tabbed bc it was not a fixed length, this way all columns line up (for anything less than a year ago). Wanted to make it line up all of the time, but this is as far as I got before I ran out of time (ironically).

Hope this helps!

If you have suggestions to improve this answer for the relative year case (not just grepping out the year) happy to hear them too, feel free to edit this answer to add them if you know how to do it.

#### Edit:

I decided to try out the `%<(n)` syntax suggested by another person too, I found that it is too short if you have anything over 9 years bc 10 years is one more digit using `%<(20)` which was suggested. Instead I suggest `%<(23)`

```sh
git log --pretty=format:"%C(magenta) %h %C(cyan)%C(bold)%ad%Creset %<(23) %C(cyan)%cr%Creset %s%C(green)%Creset" --date=short`
```

Unless the project is over 100 years old it will line up great. But if you want it to work for that you just add 1 making it `%<(24)`

Comment: `%x09` is what I was looking for! Works great piped into Visidata: `git log --pretty=format:%h%x09%aI%x09%an | vd -f tsv --header 0 -`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the tabular format is the fact that you might run out of space ...

The following one is my personal best compromise between the essential stuff to display:

- who
- did what
- and when
- to be able to dig more by the commit hash for the `how`

so:

```
  git log --pretty --format='%h %aI %<(15)%an ::: %s'
```

or

```
 git log --pretty --format='%h %cI %<(15)%an ::: %s'
```

[if you want to get the commiter time and not the author time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857467/65706)

Answer (score 0):

This is give you the **last 20 changes** in nice view with **numbering**; You can change the colors

`git log --pretty=format:"%C(magenta)%h %C(cyan)%C(bold)%ad %C(green)%<(20,trunc)%an%x09%Creset%C(yellow)%s%Creset" --date=short --color=always | head -20| cat -n`

Answer (score 0):

All those answers work well with ASCII characters, like [insysion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978908/insysion)'s [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39249439/6309):

```
git log --pretty=format:'%w(79, 0, 29)%h %<(20,trunc)%an %s' -10
```

But that breaks down for UTF-8 characters.

With Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), "[`git diff --stat`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d5a4d86a652ababe2ee1bbd27dcf0ccd30dd1c0/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L198)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgt,ltname-widthgt,ltcountgt))</sup> etc.
were invented back when everything was ASCII and `strlen()` was a way to measure the display width of a string; adjust them to compute the display width assuming UTF-8 pathnames.

See [commit ce8529b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce8529b2bbabcb5240bdcc73bccaafa1116c5d7a) (21 Oct 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 12fc4ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12fc4ad89e23af642a8614371ff80bc67cb3315d) (14 Sep 2022) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7d5a4d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d5a4d86a652ababe2ee1bbd27dcf0ccd30dd1c0), 28 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12fc4ad89e23af642a8614371ff80bc67cb3315d): use `utf8_strwidth()` to count display width
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Alexander Meshcheryakov</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Torsten Bögershausen</sup>

> When Unicode filenames (encoded in UTF-8) are used, the visible width on the screen is not the same as `strlen()`.
>
> For example, [`git log --stat`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12fc4ad89e23af642a8614371ff80bc67cb3315d/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L198)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---statltwidthgt,ltname-widthgt,ltcountgt))</sup> may produce an output like this:
>
> ```
> [snip the header]
>
> Arger.txt  | 1 +
> Ärger.txt | 1 +
> 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
> ```
>
> A side note: the original report was about cyrillic filenames.
> After some investigations it turned out that
>
> - a) This is not a problem with "ambiguous characters" in Unicode
> - b) The same problem exists for all Unicode code points (so we can use Latin based Umlauts for demonstrations below)
>
> The '`Ä`' takes the same space on the screen as the '`A`'.
> But needs one more byte in memory, so the the `git log --stat` output for "`Arger.txt`" (!) gets misaligned: The maximum length is derived from "`Ärger.txt`", 10 bytes in memory, 9 positions on the screen.
> That is why "`Arger.txt`" gets one extra ' ' for alignment, it needs 9 bytes in memory.
> If there was a file "`Ö`", it would be correctly aligned by chance, but "`Öhö`" would not.
>
> The solution is of course, to use `utf8_strwidth()` instead of `strlen()` when dealing with the width on screen.
>
> And then there is another problem, code like this: `strbuf_addf(&out, "%-*s", len, name);` (or using the underlying `snprintf()` function) does not align the buffer to a minimum of `len` measured in screen-width, but uses the memory count.
>
> One could be tempted to wish that `snprintf()` was UTF-8 aware.
> That doesn't seem to be the case anywhere (tested on Linux and Mac), probably `snprintf()` uses the "bytes in memory"/`strlen()` approach to be compatible with older versions and this will never change.
>
> The basic idea is to change code in [`diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12fc4ad89e23af642a8614371ff80bc67cb3315d/diff.c) like this `strbuf_addf(&out, "%-*s", len, name);`
>
> into something like this:
>
> ```c
> int padding = len - utf8_strwidth(name);
> if (padding < 0)
>   padding = 0;
> strbuf_addf(&out, " %s%*s", name, padding, "");
> ```
>
> The real change is slightly bigger, as it, as well, integrates two calls of `strbuf_addf()` into one.
>
> Tests: Two things need to be tested:
>
> - The calculation of the maximum width
> - The calculation of padding
>
> The name "`textfile`" is changed into "`tëxtfilë`", both have a width of 8.
> If `strlen()` was used, to get the maximum width, the shorter "`binfile`" would have been mis-aligned:
>
> ```
> binfile    | [snip]
> tëxtfilë | [snip]
> ```
>
> If only "`binfile`" would be renamed into "`binfilë`":
>
> ```
> binfilë | [snip]
> textfile | [snip]
> ```
>
> In order to verify that the width is calculated correctly everywhere,
>
> - "`binfile`" is renamed into "`binfilë`", giving 1 bytes more in `strlen()`
> - "`tëxtfile`" is renamed into "`tëxtfilë`", 2 byte more in `strlen()`.
>
> The updated [`t4012-diff-binary.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/12fc4ad89e23af642a8614371ff80bc67cb3315d/t/t4012-diff-binary.sh#L115-L132) checks the correct alignment:
>
> ```
> binfilë  | [snip]
> tëxtfilë | [snip]
> ```

---

The output from "[`git diff --stat`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e57caee004362ee855a3bc8fc826abe251eb64f8/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L198)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---statltwidthgt,ltname-widthgt,ltcountgt))</sup> on an unmerged path lost the terminating LF in Git 2.39, which has been corrected with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023).

See [commit 209d9cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/209d9cb0114dff72e96d58bb3c27409660f1b45c) (14 Dec 2022) by [Peter Grayson (`jpgrayson`)](https://github.com/jpgrayson).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e57caee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e57caee004362ee855a3bc8fc826abe251eb64f8), 26 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/209d9cb0114dff72e96d58bb3c27409660f1b45c): fix regression with `--stat` and unmerged file
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Peter Grayson</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Jeff King</sup>

> A regression was introduced in [12fc4ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12fc4ad89e23af642a8614371ff80bc67cb3315d) (`diff.c`: use utf8_strwidth() to count display width, 2022-09-14, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d5a4d86a652ababe2ee1bbd27dcf0ccd30dd1c0) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/63bba4fdd86d80ef061c449daa97a981a9be0792)).
>
> That causes missing newlines after "Unmerged" entries in [`git diff --cached --stat`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/209d9cb0114dff72e96d58bb3c27409660f1b45c/Documentation/git-diff.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> output.
>
> This problem affects v2.39.0-rc0 through v2.39.0.
>
> Add the missing newline along with a new test to cover this behavior.