Git log using since and until shows no commits
We have a repository with 50k+ commits and recently when I want to filter the commits from Jan 24 to Feb 24, it doesn't show any commits but there were 1000's of commits on that month. Any idea what might be wrong? Same happens until April and after then it was fine.
Git version: 2.43.0
git log origin/master --since='01-01-2024' --until='01-02-2024'
Expected output:
To display commits which are committed on Jan'24.
Result:
Nothing

Try with the following: git log origin/master --since='2024-01-01' --until='2024-02-01'

Or you can try with --since-as-filter= https://stackoverflow.com/q/67590215/21105992

@MicheleDeFalco quoting makes no difference at all to what Git sees here.

Note that --since and --until are taking committer date into account, not author date. Might be important if the "1000's of commits on that month" is something you're basing on author dates. If someone rebased a series of commits from that month on the next month, committer dates will have moved.

@Yaseen Tried that command as well but no success.

@teapot418 This seems to work with since-as-filter. Thanks

Add '.midnight' to your dates, and specify the months by name. '01.Jan.2024.midnight'.  Wall clock defaults to the current wall clock, and it's not clear that you're not asking for only a 24-hour period.
