# How can I consult all commits project after a specific time?

Tags: git, gitlab

On a git project, I would like to get the list of all commits that have been made after 6pm for a given user. Every day, since the creation of the project, must be taken into account in the research. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14618022/how-does-git-log-since-count) may help you.

Comment: In this example, dates are specified. In my case, I want to filter hours everyday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
git log --author=gitster --format="%H %aI" | grep -E 'T(1[89]|2)' | cut -d' ' -f1
```

This requires a relatively recent Git version for the `%aI` format, which is the author time; if you want the committer time, use `%cI`.  You can use both if you want either one.  And, of course, you'll want to change the author to something else.

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of all commits made after 6PM local time on April 10th, 2020:
`git log --date=local --after="2020-04-10T18:00:00"`

Answer (score 0):

Other answers will work if you want to see commits after a given date and time. If you want to see all commits made after 6pm *everyday*, you could use something like this:

`git log --pretty="format:%H %ad %an" --date iso | awk "/(18|19|20|21|22|23):[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/ {print}"`

To further filter by username you can just slap a `grep` on the end like `... | grep myusername`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it's a good idea, but the awk command doesn't seem to work : hours are not filtered.

Comment: @Ngb01Try it again, I found out `awk` prefers `[[:digit:]]` over `\d`

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, but not work again. I give you some data, maybe can help. Sorry for indent.
`78e5111454545465 2020-04-05 19:05:02 +0200 Paul  \n
78e5111454545465 2020-04-05 18:48:01 +0200 Paul  \n
78e5111454545465 2020-04-04 21:57:05 +0200 Paul  \n
78e5111454545465 2020-03-29 13:19:13 +0200 Paul  \n
78e5111454545465 2020-03-28 13:41:37 +0100 Paul  \n
78e5111454545465 2020-03-22 21:08:19 +0100 Paul  \n
78e5111454545465 2020-03-22 13:51:39 +0100 Paul  \n
78e5111454545465 2020-03-21 08:57:49 +0100 Paul  \n
78e5111454545465 2020-03-21 08:27:36 +0100 Paul`