# How to find when a cherry-picked commit was added to a branch

Tags: git

A commit from 2 weeks was cherry-picked to the top of a branch today and the git log shows the date on the commit to be from 2 weeks ago. But how can I see that it was added to the branch today?

I use IntelliJ and it's annotations show it as added to the branch today but `git annotate` shows the date from 2 weeks ago. There must be some way to do it since IntelliJ does it.

Comment: [`git log --format=fuller`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)?

Comment: That does it! I guess IntelliJ must be pulling the commitDate in it's annotate function.

Comment: Yep, the difference between the two is sometimes unintuitive (esp. when a date you see isn't labeled as being one or the other).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why git AuthorDate is different from CommitDate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856983/why-git-authordate-is-different-from-commitdate)