# Getting a commit count for each file in a git repository

Tags: git, github

I'm looking for a way to see statistics about how often each file in a git repository has been changed. Basically how often a file has been committed and was actually different from the previous version.

Additionally, is there a way to get the date when a file was last changed?

I'm a git novice and haven't found anything about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Like this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/278192/7362396 - or do you mean multiple at once ("each") in like a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's two approaches.

You can use `git ls-files` to get a list of all files.

You can use `git log --oneline <file>` to get a list of all commits which affected that file, each on one line. Then pipe it to `wc -l` to get a count.

Put them together with your favorite programming language.

This is useful if you only want to look at a few files.

---

You can use `git log --pretty=format: --name-only` to get a list of all files changed in each commit. Commits are separated by newlines. For example...

```
$ git log --pretty=format: --name-only
benchmark/README.md

benchmark/README.md
benchmark/app_erb.rb
benchmark/app_erb.yml
benchmark/erb_render.rb
benchmark/erb_render.yml

benchmark/README.md

benchmark/README.md
```

This shows `benchmark/README.md` changed 4 times and the rest changed once.

Parse it with your favorite programming language.

This is more efficient if you want to scan the whole history.

---

> *Additionally, is there a way to get the date when a file was last changed?*

Yes, `git log --pretty=format:...` allows you to customize what is shown. `%ad` shows the author date (or `%cd` for commit date, [author date and commit dateare potentially different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856983/why-git-authordate-is-different-from-commitdate)). `--date` allows you to change the date format. `git log --date=iso --pretty=format:%ad <filename>` gives you all the times a file was changed in ISO 8601 format. Add `--author-date-order` to ensure they're ordered by author date. Then add a `-1` to get just the last change.

```
$ git log -1 --author-date-order --date=iso --pretty=format:%ad somefile
2018-08-16 03:12:27 +0800
```

You can put this together with `--name-only` to get a complete listing of all commits, what files they changed, and when.

```
$ git log --author-date-order --date=iso --pretty=format:%ad --name-only
2018-07-10 16:03:51 +0000
benchmark/README.md

2018-07-10 15:58:52 +0000
benchmark/README.md
benchmark/app_erb.rb
benchmark/app_erb.yml
benchmark/erb_render.rb
benchmark/erb_render.yml

2018-07-10 15:51:29 +0000
benchmark/README.md

2018-07-10 15:49:42 +0000
benchmark/README.md
```

Answer (score 3):

If you install the very good 'git extras' tool, there is a command `git effort` to do exactly that.

https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-effort