# Find number of previous commits that made changes to a file

Tags: git, github

How do you get the total number of previous commits that made changes to a file in git?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a commit count for each file in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902038/getting-a-commit-count-for-each-file-in-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **"The number of commits that changed a file"**, and assuming that you have access to a **linux like terminal**.

You can use `git log  --pretty=format:"%H"  <PATH> | wc`

See
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-git-logs/