# How to synchronize time between local and origin in git?

Tags: git, github

My commit time differs between origin and local. The time in local is right. I have tried `git push -f` but that does not work. I believe that it is related to the git rebase but I don't know how to fix it.Is there a way to make my commit time in origin the same as my local commit time?

[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't an issue Git can resolve. You need to ensure that the system clocks on the relevant machines are accurate.

Comment: But see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11856983/1126841

Comment: @chepner, thanks for your answer, but system clock works well and I believe that github remote works too.

Comment: See the above link. I suspect the problem is not that the times are out of sync, but that you are looking at two different timestamps on the same commit.

Comment: Thanks for your link, my laptop isn't at hand so I will check later.

Comment: What's the output from `git show 3f2af8f`? Commits have two timestamps, an **author** timestamp and a **commit** timestamp. If you `commit --amend` or `rebase` they can differ. Commit times *also* include your time **zone**. Perhaps the web site is converting time zone.

Comment: @chepner You are right! The author time differs from commit time! Thank you!

Comment: @amphetamachine Also thanks for your answer! The link above is the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try inspecting the output from `git show 3f2af8f` or `git cat-file -p 3f2af8f`.

Commit times also include your time zone. If the system time zone is not set correctly on your computer, they may be hours off. Perhaps the web site you're viewing the commit details under is converting the time zone.

### More on commit time stamps

Commits have two timestamps, an **author** timestamp and a **commit** timestamp. If you `commit --amend` or `rebase` they can differ.

If you inspect the commit directly using `git cat-file -p <commit>`, you can see the timestamps in [UNIX Epoch seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)).

I had to `commit --amend` this commit, so the times are different. I've underlined the timestamp in red, and the time zone in blue:

[image: git cat-file -p HEAD]

You can actually specify the timestamps git uses when adding commits using some operations. `commit --amend --date=now` or `--date='2023-01-13 13:13:13'` or `rebase --committer-date-is-author-date` to name a few tricks.