# find out who created a branch on a remote git repository

Tags: git

I'm pruning some branches off of a git remote.

How can I find out who created a branch on a remote git repository?

Maybe there is something similar to `git branch -r --show-user`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is pretty simple:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' | sort
```

Taken from:
[Find out a Git branch creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055198/find-out-git-branch-creator/19135644)

Comment: This is giving some branches which already deleted in remote, how to eliminate those in result?

Comment: @Pand005 I'd remove them with `git branch -d <branch-name>`

Comment: CAUTION: This command doesn't find the **creator** of the branch, only *the last person who committed*.

Answer (score 3):

See `.git/logs/refs/heads/BRANCHNAME`. The first line should contain information about the creation of the branch, including the user who created it and the commit from which the branch "forked".

`git reflog` can be used to examine the file programmatically; see `git help reflog` for details.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything here other than information on *local* branches.  There won't be any information about branches created remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a completely general answer to this in all cases. Consider:

```
A----B----C
      \
       D----E----F
             \
              G----H----I
```

Where was the branch containing commit I created? Was it a branch created from E, or from B. Both are possibilities - in one case, you have a branch created at D from B, then another branch created at G from E, in the other, you have D created from B, and then F created from E - in other words, the same tree could be represented like this:

```
A----B----C
      \
       D----E----G----H----I
             \
              F
```

Or even this:

```
A----B----D----E----G----H----I
      \         \
       C         F
```

All three of the above are topologically equivalent, and all three would give different answers to "where did branch I start?"...

Comment: Branch `I` started with the commit from which it first branched. It's not apparent from the dag alone, but the information is retained by `git`.

Comment: @chepner True, if all branches were created locally. However, if `userA@repoA` creates the branch, pushes it to `origin`, and then `userB@repoB` fetches and tracks that branch, and adds more to it, that information is likely not available to `userB@repoB` without considerable forensic effort... In the general case, all you have is the DAG. Date stamps, etc. may add some additional information, but it's not a simple one-liner in general...