# How to get all branches with someone’s commits using git?

Tags: git, git-bash

How can I get the names of all branches that someone made a commit to in the last month?

Comment: Not sure, but I feel it might need some  custom logic.  Git does not provide this out of the box.  A reporting API on top of Git is a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is not a full-baked answer, just an idea.

---

#### A little technical background before the actual answer.

A Git branch is just a pointer to a commit. It can change from one history branch to another and, apart from an entry in the branch's reflog (if it is enabled), the movement of a branch doesn't leave any trace in the repository.

To make it clear, let's say the repo looks like this:

```
               +-- branch X
               v
A -- B -- C -- D 
       \
        - E -- F
               ^
               +-- branch Y
```

This simple sequence of commands:

```
git checkout X
git reset --hard F
git checkout Y
git reset --hard D
```

makes branches `X` and `Y` swap their places. Now the repository looks like this:

```
               +-- branch Y
               v
A -- B -- C -- D 
       \
        - E -- F
               ^
               +-- branch X
```

The commit `E`, for example, now belongs to branch `X` and cannot be reached from branch `Y` but it belonged to branch `Y` (and couldn't be reached from branch `X`) when it was created.

**This makes your question indeterminate.**

---

#### The answer

The command to use is [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) with some parameters:

> `--since=<date>`
> `--after=<date>`
>
> Show commits more recent than a specific date.
>
> `--until=<date>`
> `--before=<date>`
>
> Show commits older than a specific date.
>
> `--author=<pattern>`
> `--committer=<pattern>`
>
> Limit the commits output to ones with author/committer header lines that match the specified pattern (regular expression).
>
> `--all`
>
> Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.
>
> `--walk-reflogs`
>
> Instead of walking the commit ancestry chain, walk reflog entries from the most recent one to older ones.

The command line should be something like this:

```
git log --since='1 month ago' --author=john.doe@example.org --all
```

You can put the complete name or email address of the author or just a fragment of it in the `--author` argument.

`--all` tells `git log` to search the commits accessible using all the current branches

If you add `--walk-reflogs` to the command line and replace `--all` with a specific branch name (f.e. `Y` in the example from the first part of this answer), Git follows the movement history of the `Y` branch (recorded in the reflog) and returns commits `F`, `E`, `B` and `A`. Without `--walk-reflogs` Git follows the commits accessible from the current position of branch `Y` and returns the commits `D`, `C`, `B` and `A` (assuming all of them match the other conditions).

*Be aware that adding `--walk-reflogs` can return incomplete results or nothing. The branch's [reference log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) contains the movement of the branch (because of `commit`, `reset`, `rebase` and other commands) **on the local repository only**, it can be disabled or cleared*

Comment: thx for your help :D
I manage to write something like this with help from someone else answer

git log --since='2016-11-01' --author=piotr.stolarczyk@novo-technologies.com --all --format="%H" | while read i; do git branch --contains $i; done | sort -u

this is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that enough: `git branch -av`? It also shows potential remote branches.
`-a` stands for all, `-v` for verbose. See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) for more details.

**Edit**: I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5188364/5784831) gives a good overview over further possibilities. However, the [branch creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055198/find-out-git-branch-creator) is not tracked. Depending on the question `git blame file` might be interesting...

Comment: Where are the "someone" and the "last month" taken into account?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "someone" and "last month". A kind of subset of the list given by the command above? Ideally, provide an example of the situation and the expected output.

Comment: Well, read the question. OP wants the branches were "someone", lets call him "Frank", did commit within the last month.

Comment: That is what I would also guess after he put someone in quotation marks.

Comment: @Vampire See my edit. I hope there are some good links now ;-)

Comment: To be honest, I still don't think your answer is related enough to the question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "--since" option to git log to select commits within the last month:

```
git log --since="`date -d'1 month ago'`"
```

Then for each of those revisions you can use "git branch --contains" to show which branches it was in. e.g:

```
git branch --contains 00735a997d0bba684dbf62552eea83b9491ac26b
```

You can put this all together in a single line which will do it all for you and de-duplicate the output:

```
git log --since="`date -d'1 month ago'`" --format="%H" | while read i; do git branch --contains $i; done | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not possible.

You can find out in which branches commits of a user are contained that have an author date within the last month or that have a commit date within the last month. Both is potentially not very accurate.

What you cannot do is to determine to which branch a commit was made in Git. A Branch is just a post-it note on a commit that moves on to the next commit automatically if the branch is checked out. But you can peel-off the post-it and place it anywhere you like at any time. So you cannot determine to which branch a commit was done and as commit and author dates can be arbitrarily set you cannot even reliably use those dates.

You can maybe do such a thing if you have strict commit policies and they are obeyed by all people.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `since` & `untill` flag to see the commits of a date range. And use `author` flag to filter the someone's commits.

```
$ git log --since=2.month.ago --until=1.month.ago --author=<user>    # relative time
$ git log --since=2000-01-01 --until=2012-12-21 --author=<user>      # absolute
```

Then if you want to know that which branch(es) contains a specific commit.

```
$ git branch --contains <commit-sha>          # show the branch list(s) containing the commit
```