# Search all branches created by a user in a GitHub repository

Tags: git, github, git-branch

There was a branch created by a user (`knownUserName`) in our code repository (`repoEx`). Where he committed and `push`ed a few of his changes, but he didn't create a pull request for the same.

It has been long and there is an exponential increase in the number of branches that the repository now has because of which we are unable to go through all the branches and find the one created by him.

**Is there a way to search all the branches using the *`git`* command line or *`GitHub`* interface, to find all the *branches* created by a user in a specific repository?**

I tried using the GitHub interface and filtering the branches (under `https://github.com/repoEx/branches/all`) using the search parameter as -

```
author:<knownUserName>
```

but this won't work. The search seems to be effective with a branch name, but I don't have any clue about the name.

Comment: You can get list of unmerged branch `git branch --no-merged`

Comment: @Ôrel I guess that is returning list of those branches that I have created and are not yet merged.

Comment: For me there is no branch creator, you just know author and submitter of commit, once you have the branch list, if it is a very long list, you can get author of the last commit of each branch to find the branch

Comment: @Ôrel Okay, in the current case, the creator, author and submitter is the same `knownUserName` and the suggested answer is still not working if I run it using bash.

Comment: branch is not an entity on git which contains an creator. a Branch is just a sequence of commits and a name basically

Comment: @pedrorijo91 I understand that fact, but then with the only information being the username, I would eventually want to move in the direction of finding the branch(specific sequence of commits) which has the required commits from the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop on the branch, display the last commit information, and grep on the username.

You will have the commit id you are looking for:

```
for co in `git branch -a --no-merge`; do  git log -1 --no-walk --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" $co; done | grep <knownUserName>
```

Comment: Update with `-a` to get all branches

Comment: I got an unusual error with this. `fatal: unrecognized argument: ->`

Comment: Have you strange characters into branch name ?

Comment: Can you try to put the grep part into the loop `for co in \`git branch -a --no-merge\`; do git log -1 --no-walk --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s" $co | grep Georges; done ` ?

Answer (score 11):

This is for OS X. Just adding grep on to [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19135644/8047) and modifying for email, you get

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authoremail) %09 %(refname)' | sort -k5n -k2M -k3n -k4n | grep <author-email>
```

which works quite well.

[Other answer did not work for me, not sure why]

Answer (score -5):

CLick on branches and after that you will see an option saying your branches [Click here to see the image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5PI1.png)