# How to get the author name of a Git repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm doing a Git repository viewer, and I need to get the name of the repository author and email.

The following command returns me the author of a commit.

```
git show --format="%aN <%aE>"
```

I need it to return the author of the repository.

Comment: I think the author that you mention refers to the repository owner. The git repository itself does not store any infomation about the owner. And the owner could be a team instead of one person. Although it's not always true, we can still assume the root commit is made by the repository owner. `git log <branch> --max-parents=0 --format="%an <%ae>"`. Note that the branch may have more than one root commit.

Answer (score 1):

Git does not store any meta data for the owner of the repository. But you can list the commits in ascending order time with:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' | sort -k5n -k2M -k3n -k4n
```

Please refer to *[Find out a Git branch creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055198)*.