# git for-each-ref - filter results by age

Tags: git

I'm using the following command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39251131/5812876):

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(color:cyan)%(authordate:format:%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p)    %(align:25,left)%(color:yellow)%(authorname)%(end) %(color:reset)%(refname:strip=3)' --sort=authordate refs/remotes
```

Is there a way to sort `authordate` by a specific date?

For example, only show results that are X days or months old, or perhaps after a given date? I was thinking about using `grep` but I was hoping there was an approach that actually parses the given date to do the calculations rather than just string matching.

I came up with the following using `sed`:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(color:cyan)%(authordate:format:%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p)    %(align:25,left)%(color:yellow)%(authorname)%(end) %(color:reset)%(refname:strip=3)' --sort=authordate refs/remotes | sed -n '/{start_year}-*/,/{end_year}-{end_month}-*/p'
```

but it would be much better to just give one specific date and get all results before or after said date.

EDIT: The method above using `sed` doesn't work if the given end date doesn't exist since sed is only a stream editor. For example, if the resulting sed string is `'/2017-*/,/2018-10-*/p'` but there are no entries matching `2018-10-*` (no branches with commits in the month of October of 2018) then it will get all of the results from 2017 onward. That is, it isn't a true date range calculation; it's a simple string matching that stop when it finds the first entry matching the right side.

Comment: Get the author date in seconds-since-epoch format, use that to select the ones you're interested in—this is a simple date >= start && state <= end kind of comparison—and *then* format the date stamps to make them pretty.

Answer (score 6):

Neither the [git-for-each-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref) nor [git-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) commands provide an option to filter by date.

However, it's pretty trivial to filter the output of either one with AWK, but first we need to use an ISO 8601 date format (`yyyy-MM-dd`) to make the comparison easy. Also, the colour won't survive the pass through AWK (well, I don't know how to make it do that), so we might as well lose it.

Here's how to do it with your format:

```
git for-each-ref \
    refs/remotes \
    --sort=authordate \
    --format='%(authordate:format:%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p)  %(align:25,left)%(authorname)%(end) %(refname:strip=3)'  \
    | awk '{ if ($1 < "2021-11-23") print $0 }'
```

Alternatively, this command will just print the name of local branches whose latest commit date (different to author date) was before the date inside the AWK program:

```
git branch --sort=-committerdate --format='%(committerdate:short) %(refname:short)' \
    | awk '{ if ($1 < "2021-11-23") { print $2 } }'
```

Comment: thanks for your `authordate:format:%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p` format !