# List unmerged Git branches from the last 2 months

Tags: git

It is fairly easy to [list branches *sorted* by date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2514172/241142).  For example, the following command gives me a nice columnar output showing relative date, branch name, and commiter.

```
git for-each-ref --sort='-committerdate:iso8601' --format='%(committerdate:relative)|%(refname:short)|%(committername)' refs/remotes/ | column -s '|' -t
```

But what about *filtering* by date?  What if I want to only see branches from the last 2 months?  Is there any straightforward way to do that?

What about filtering out all branches that are already merged into `main`?

Ideally I would keep the ability to sort by date, but the 2 filters are more important than the sorting.

Also I'd love to be able to use all stored dates and include the branch if any of the dates are recent.  I believe these include `authordate`, `commiterdate`, `creatordate`, and `taggerdate`.  That might be over complicated, though, and is not essential.

#### Updates:

1. Apparently filtering by merge status is easy with `--no-merged=main`.
2. It looks like filtering by date might be possible with `%(if)...%(then)...%(else)...%(end)`, but I haven't worked out the details yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70456463/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+for-each-ref+filter+date