# How can I list all Git tags created after a certain date/time?

Tags: git

I want to list all of the tags in my Git repository that were created after a certain timestamp. For argument's sake, let's say I want all the tags created after July 16th, 2023 at midnight in the eastern US time zone. After some searching online, I was inclined to do something like this:

```bash
git log --tags --no-walk --after="2023-07-16T00:00:00-04:00" --pretty="format:%S"
```

However, there is a problem with this approach. The `--after` option considers the timestamps of the commit(s) that went into the tag, not the actual tag creation time. So, for example, if I created a tag on July 17th based on a commit from July 15th, it would not be returned by this command.

I also explored `git for-each-ref`. This command is aware of the actual creation timestamps for tags. For example, this will list all of the tags in the repo along with their creation timestamp:

```bash
git for-each-ref --sort=taggerdate --format '%(tag) %(taggerdate)'
```

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to filter it to only show tags created after a certain timestamp.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do using Git commands?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70456463/7976758

Answer (score 1):

As a lightweight tag does not store its creation date, I assume you are interested in only annotated tags. In `--after="2023-07-16T00:00:00-04:00"` the `iso-strict` format is used. One idea is to list annotated tags with one `taggerdate` in `unix` format and another in `iso-strict` format. Get the epoch of `2023-07-16T00:00:00-04:00` and compare it with the `taggerdate` in `unix` format. Print the tag whose `taggerdate` is bigger than the epoch.

```
d=$(date --date='2023-07-16T00:00:00-04:00' +"%s")
git for-each-ref refs/tags \
    --format='%(objecttype) %(tag) %(taggerdate:unix) %(taggerdate:iso-strict)' \
    --sort=taggerdate | while read ot tg td1 td2;do
        if [[ "$ot" != tag ]];then
            continue
        fi
        if [[ "$td1" -gt "$d" ]];then
            echo ${tg} ${td2}
        fi
    done
```