# How can I see all remote branches pushed by me

Tags: git, version-control, git-tfs

I know `git branch -r` shows all remote branches but I want to see only those that I created using `git push`.

It will be a bonus if someone could show how to delete only my remote branches safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of branch author, but you canlist branches by:

- [their last commit author](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39251131/6309)
- [their first commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42281493/6309) (which is closer to what you are after), but... that assumes the branch was made from `master`, and it hasn't been merged to `master` yet

In short, due to the nature of branches (a pointer to a commit, which can be overridden/deleted at any time), this is not 100% reliable.

See "[How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/6309)" for deleting a remote branch: you can push a branch deletion.

```
git push <remote_name> --delete <branch_name>
```

Comment: what are those colors in first link? what is I place there?

Comment: @Imad just decoration, nothing to "place". The version without colors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19135644/6309