# Get List of merged branches on github along with branch creator

Tags: git, github

We have a team of 50+ developers and people do not delete their feature branches after merging them on the main-stream branch.

We have four main-stream branches `develop`, `staging`, `demo`, and `master`. We follow to create a separate branch for each JIRA ticket and that branch should be deleted once it merged on the origin branch.

So I want to get the list of **all merged branches along with the creator** to prepare the stats but could not find a proper way to do this. Find multiple answers on StackOverflow but could not find any suitable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know if a branch has been already merged into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master)

Comment: @RajatMishra No, It does not show branch creator.

Comment: GitHub does not provide a way to query who created a branch.  You can see who created the commits on the branch, but if I pushed commits created by someone else, you could not tell I was the pusher.

Comment: Git itself does not store any information about who created a branch name (because that's pointless; branch names are not important). GitHub could store this information somewhere outside Git, but doesn't (because that's pointless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git for-each-ref` with `--merged=HEAD` to filter on merged branch then use a format to get the committer by getting the last person to commit to that branch.

```
git for-each-ref --merged=HEAD --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' --sort=committerdate
```

You can add a `grep` on `refs/remotes/origin/` to get only remote branches

```
git for-each-ref --merged=HEAD --format='%(committerdate) %09 %(authorname) %09 %(refname)' --sort=committerdate | grep 'refs/remotes/origin/'
```

From [Find out a Git branch creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055198/find-out-a-git-branch-creator/19135644#19135644) and [How can I know if a branch has been already merged into master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226976/how-can-i-know-if-a-branch-has-been-already-merged-into-master)

Comment: `--no-merged=HEAD` It will give non-merged branch, but I need merged branches. Also I need to check whether branch is merged on the point it created instead of checking whether branch is merged on master.

Comment: I have updated for `merged` I don't understand what you call the `point it created.` You can run this on command on the different main-stream branch, but if you merge `develop` in `master` you will have duplicated. as the branch will be in the history of several main-stream branch

Comment: I ran the above-provided command and it printed lots of branches but when I searched some of these branches on the GitHub repo, they don't exist.

Comment: You should clean your local clone if you have object in local that are not on the server.

Comment: You can check remote branch with `git branch -r`