git command to display un-merged branches for particular user in master repo
git command to display un-merged branches for particular user in master repo
git branch -a --no-merged master

Used above command but unable to filter with specific user, as unmegred branches volume is 3k need to clean up them..

What is a "user for a branch"? You can only see the user of a commit and a branch is nothing more as an pointer to the last commit of this branch. Or do you want to find out the creator of a branch ( which is simply the user who did the first commit to a branch ) Or you want to see all people working with this branch... many options :-)

maybe some useful infos already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12055198/find-out-a-git-branch-creator

I Just want to see list of who created branch, but not merged any code changes..

Delegate cleanup to the users. Also, make it part of your workflow to delete merged branches, preferably as part of merging them.

Assuming "for particular user" means the author or committer of the last commit at the tip, use whatever you want to generate candidate commits and git log to filter and annotate the list:
git for-each-ref --no-merged=master --format='%(objectname)' refs/heads refs/remotes \
| git log --no-walk --stdin --pretty='%h %an %d' --author="your name here" # or --committer= and %cn, or whatever.

git log's --no-walk says you don't want histories, you're just after info about specific commits. --stdin says you're generating the list and feeding it in that way, the rest is all as usual.
edit: staircase wit says "duh, git log can find all the branches and remotes itself."
git log --no-walk --branches --remotes --pretty='%h %an %d' --author=Jim


git branch -r --no-merged | xargs git show --no-patch --oneline --format='%cI %h %an %S' | grep "$(git config user.name)"


-r: Remote Branches or `-a`: for all branches
--no-merged:  Branches which are unmerged
`|` pipe that command to `git show`
xargs: passes each branch listed to `git show`
--no-patch: suppress the diff output
--oneline: pretty prints the output
--format:
  - %cI: ISO8601 date format
  - %h: abbreviated commit hash
  - %an: Author name
  - %S: ref name
`|` pipe that command to `grep`
-- grep: grep the author configured at `git config user.name`


if you want a particular user name or email, you can grep that directly too.  | grep "<string>"
