# How can I set maximum field lenghs for git log prettyprint?

Tags: git

How can I specify maximum field lengths with git log? I want the output columns to be aligned.

Comment: If the specified width is less than the number of characters in the field, the field is not truncated.  The columns become mis-aligned.

Answer (score 11):

You can specify the column width without using ANY external tool at all:

```
git log --format="%<(25,trunc)%ad | %<(25,trunc)%s | %<(25,trunc)%an"
```

There are TONs of other options, e.g.

```
%<|(25)
```

to align the output to columns. You can format columns to be left bound, right bound or even centered and so on: https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Unfortunately I do not know when this has been added to git, I am using 2.10.1 on Windows…

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows, you could use a PowerShell script. Format the log with a special character between outputs, create an object from that and pipe into `Format-Table`, where you can specify `Width`:

```
git log --format="%ad|%s|%an" | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Time = $_.Split('|')[0]
    Message = $_.Split('|')[1]
    Author = $_.Split('|')[2]
  }
} | Format-Table -Property @{Expression={$_.Time};width=25;Label="Author date"}, 
                           @{Expression={$_.Message};Width=25;Label="Commit message"}, 
                           @{Expression={$_.Author};Width=11;Label="Author name"}
```

Sample output:

```
Author date               Commit message            Author name
-----------               --------------            -----------
Sun Jun 16 12:49:03 20... added rand content 60 ... Bonke
Sun Jun 16 12:46:56 20... added rand content 61 ... Bonke
Sun Jun 16 12:46:37 20... change                    Bonke
Wed Apr 24 22:41:44 20... added rand content 17 ... Klas Mel...
Wed Apr 24 22:40:16 20... added rand content 8 t... Klas Mel...
```

If  you want to do it in bash instead here is the analogous script in bash (inspired by the answer to [Git log tabular formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631005/git-log-tabular-formatting)):

```
git log --pretty=format:'%ad|%s|%an' | 
  while IFS='|' read time message author
  do 
    printf '%.25s %.25s %.11s\n' "$time" "$message" "$author"
  done
```

sample output

```
Sun Jun 16 12:49:03 2013  added rand content 60 to  Bonke
Sun Jun 16 12:46:56 2013  added rand content 61 to  Bonke
Sun Jun 16 12:46:37 2013  change                    Bonke
Wed Apr 24 22:41:44 2013  added rand content 17 to  Klas Mellbo
Wed Apr 24 22:40:16 2013  added rand content 8 to . Klas Mellbo
```

Comment: When I use the bash version the output is not lining up if the subject is less than 25 characters.

Comment: @user2494490 try using `%-25.25` instead of `%.25`

Comment: Thanks! This works well, but I've lost the paging--the entire log prints now. I piped the output to less, but that scrolls the first line out of view. How to get back the original functionality where I can press the spacebar to page?